# Does Elasticsearch assign relevance to text fields based on their format? For example, heading, link, list item, bold, underline?

Tags: elasticsearch, text, format, relevance

Intuitively when searching a document the match (similarity score) should take into account formatting "hints", such as heading (higher = more important), link, list item, bold, underline etc., vs. simple text. Does Elasticsearch do that? If so where can I find the relevant info, such as the (default or customized) weight (importance) assigned to each such format?
I did read about weights and boosts, but both seem to be different than my question.
Thanks,
-- Shaul